# Python regex pattern to find string enclosed in preprocessor directives

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to read C++ source files with Python to extract loaded header files.
The header files are specified between `#ifdef TYPEA` and `#else` OR `#endif`. *If there is an `#else`-clause*, the header files will *always* be specified **before** the `#else`-clause.

Let's assume an excerpt of the content of the source looks like this:

```
source_content = '\n'.join([
    '#ifdef TYPEZERO',
    '  int someint = 42;',
    '#endif',
    'void abc ( int value) {',
    '  return 5 ** 2.5',
    '}',
    '',
    'abc',
    '#ifdef TYPEA',                                 # <---- begin identifier, may contain leading/trailing whitespaces
    '#include "some_header.h"',                     # <---- I want these lines
    '           #include "some_other_header23.h"',  # <---- I want these lines
    '           #else        ',                     # optional stop identifier, may contain leading/trailing whitespaces
    'double in_fact_int = 5;',                      # some irrelevant content
    '         #endif    ',                          # final stop identifier, may contain leading/trailing whitespaces
    '',
    'a = 5',
    '#ifdef TYPEB',
    '  abc = 23.5;',
    '#endif',
])
```

I'd like to extract lines with comments excluding `#ifdef TYPEA`, `#else`, `#endif`, such that my result is:

```
desired_match = '#include "some_header.h"\n           #include "some_other_header23.h"'

print(desired_match)
# Out:    #include "some_header.h"
# Out:               #include "some_other_header23.h"
```

Removing the whitespaces would be nice, but I'm fine with doing this separately from regex.

My current approach is:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(
    r'(\s*.*)#ifdef(\s+)TYPEA(\s*)(.*?)(?=((\s*)#else|(\s*)#endif))',
    re.DOTALL
)
match = re.match(pattern, source_content)

print(match.group())
# Out:    #ifdef TYPEZERO
# Out:      int someint = 42;
# Out:    #endif
# Out:    void abc ( int value) {
# Out:      return 5 ** 2.5
# Out:    }
# Out:    
# Out:    abc
# Out:    #ifdef TYPEA
# Out:    #include "some_header.h"
# Out:               #include "some_other_header23.h"
```

This works fine with cutting off `#else` or `#endif`, but as you can see `#ifdef TYPEA` and, even worse, all preceding lines are also matched.
If I remove the leading `(\s*.*)` from the pattern (or change it to `(\s*)`), then I won't see any matching.

How can I exclude the lines before `#ifdef TYPEA` and possibly also `#ifdef TYPEA` to get my desired match?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a named group. Not sure, if they are available in Python though. Your regex will become: `(\s*.*)(?P<M>#ifdef(\s+)TYPEA(\s*)(.*?)(?=((\s*)#else|(\s*)#endif)))`. Then get the group by name "M".

Comment: Doesn't `#ifdef\s+TYPEA\s*(.*?)(?=\s*#(?:else|endif))` with `re.search` (not `re.match`) work well enough for you? Why do you have so many unnecessary groups around `\s*`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know... I'm not very used to applying regex... You approach seems to be working very well, thanks! If you post it as an answer (in my other question), I'll accept and upvote it.

Comment: Haven't tried with multiple 'TYPEA' groups though. Does it only select the first with #include in this case?

Comment: If you need multiple matches, use `re.findall(r'#ifdef\s+TYPEA\s*(.*?)(?=\s*#(?:else|endif))', source_content)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pu1pOu/1). You may test it [here](https://ideone.com/th5JDU).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using named groups. You had solved most of the problem already.

Notice the change in the regex to include the `#ifdef...` part within `(?P<M>...)`.

```py
import re

source_content = '\n'.join([
    '#ifdef TYPEZERO',
    '  int someint = 42;',
    '#endif',
    'void abc ( int value) {',
    '  return 5 ** 2.5',
    '}',
    '',
    'abc',
    '#ifdef TYPEA',                                 # <---- begin identifier, may contain leading/trailing whitespaces
    '#include "some_header.h"',                     # <---- I want these lines
    '           #include "some_other_header23.h"',  # <---- I want these lines
    '           #else        ',                     # optional stop identifier, may contain leading/trailing whitespaces
    'double in_fact_int = 5;',                      # some irrelevant content
    '         #endif    ',                          # final stop identifier, may contain leading/trailing whitespaces
    '',
    'a = 5',
    '#ifdef TYPEB',
    '  abc = 23.5;',
    '#endif',
])

pattern = re.compile(
    r'(\s*.*)#ifdef(\s+)TYPEA(\s*)(?P<M>(.*?)(?=((\s*)#else|(\s*)#endif)))',
    re.DOTALL
)
match = re.match(pattern, source_content)

print(match.group( "M" ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.search` instead of `re.match` and use group numbers to get parts of your regex results.

```py
pattern = re.compile(
    r'\s+#ifdef\s+TYPEA\s*(.*?)(?=(\s*#else|\s*#endif))',
    re.DOTALL
)
match = re.search(pattern, source_content)

print(match.group(1))
```

Is it solving your problem?

Comment: Thanks, this also works very well! Sree Kumar's solution also excludes the `#ifdef TYPEA` without having to use a - probably changing - group numbering. Thus I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want what's between `#ifdef TYPEA` and `#else` or `#endif`, you can match the whole thing and create a group between those keywords. `re.findall` will return the group:

```
import re
comment_pattern = re.compile(r'#ifdef TYPEA(.*?)(?:#else|#endif)', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
print(*re.findall(comment_pattern, source_content), sep='\n-------------\n')
```

Output:

```
#include "some_header.h"
           #include "some_other_header23.h"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution. But in contrast Sree Kumar's solution this returns a list of groups depending on preceeding whitespaces.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `findall` returns all occurrences of your pattern in the string whereas `match` will match the pattern from the beginning of the string (the reason why you need the preceding characters `.*` in your expression). I removed the other whitespaces to keep the expression simple but I think you get the idea...

Comment: All this to say the other solution is fine as long as you expect only one match per string

Comment: Yep, I expect only one match per string. Thanks again for your help!