# Find string enclosed in preprocessor directives - with interfering lines

Tags: python, regex

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257671/python-regex-pattern-to-find-string-enclosed-in-preprocessor-directives).

I'm trying to read C++ source files with Python to extract loaded header files.
The header files are specified between `#ifdef TYPEA` and `#else` OR `#endif`. *If there is an `#else`-clause*, the header files will *always* be specified **before** the `#else`-clause.

Let's assume an excerpt of the content of the source looks like this:

```
source_content = '\n'.join([
    'void abc ( int value) {',
    '  return 5 ** 2.5',
    '}',
    '',
    'abc',
    '',
    '#ifdef TYPEA',                                 # <---- begin identifier, may contain leading/trailing whitespaces
    'some_var_is_set = 42.42;',     # <---- I do not need these lines, but it's ok to get them
    '// some annoying comment',     # <---- I do not need these lines, but it's ok to get them
    '#include "some_header.h"',                     # <---- I want these lines
    '           #include "some_other_header23.h"',  # <---- I want these lines
    '// another comment',           # <---- I do not need these lines, but it's ok to get them
    '    some_other_var = 3.159;',  # <---- I do not need these lines, but it's ok to get them
    '#include"some_header.h"',                      # <---- I want these lines, even though it is a dupe
    '           #else        ',                     # optional stop identifier, may contain leading/trailing whitespaces
    'double in_fact_int = 5;',                      # some irrelevant content
    '         #endif    ',                          # final stop identifier, may contain leading/trailing whitespaces
    '',
    '#ifdef TYPEB',
    '  abc = 23.5;',
    '#endif',
])
```

I'd like to extract lines 6-14 between `#ifdef TYPEA`, `#else`, `#endif`, such that my result is:

```
desired_match = 'some_var_is_set = 42.42;\n// some annoying comment\n#include "some_header.h"\n           #include "some_other_header23.h"\n// another comment\n    some_other_var = 3.159;\n#include"some_header.h"'

print(desired_match)
# Out:    some_var_is_set = 42.42;
// some annoying comment
#include "some_header.h"
           #include "some_other_header23.h"
// another comment
    some_other_var = 3.159;
#include"some_header.h"
```

Removing everything NOT including `#include` would be nice, but is not required.

My current approach is:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(
    (
        r'(\s*.*)#ifdef(\s+)TYPEA(\s*)'
        r'(?P<sources>(#include.*?)(?=((\s*)#else|(\s*)#endif)))'
    ), re.DOTALL
)
match = re.match(pattern, source_content)
```

This works fine as long as there are no comments or other statements withing the enclosing `#ifdef/#else/#endif`. But as soon as there are comments etc., no match is returned.
The **`#include`** in the `pattern` is **required**, since there will be other blocks starting with `#ifdef TYPEA` which will **not** contain any include statements, but **only one** `TYPEA`-block with includes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex with `re.search` (note `re.match` only returns matches that are found at the start of a string, so `re.search` is more versatile):

```
#ifdef\s+TYPEA\s*(.*?)(?=\s*#(?:else|endif))
```

If you need multiple matches, you can plug this regex into a `re.findall`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pu1pOu/1). *Details*:

- `#ifdef` - a fixed string
- `\s+`  - one or more whitespaces
- `TYPEA` - a fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as few as possible (also matches line break chars as `re.DOTALL` is used)
- `(?=\s*#(?:else|endif))` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces and then either `#else` or `#endif`.

See the [Python demo, too](https://ideone.com/th5JDU).